# Javascript: replacing eval to call an object?

Tags: javascript, eval

Pretty new to javascript. The following code works perfectly for me. It is a reset button on a grid of 100 boxes. Each box is a movie clip called box1, box2 etc. On mouse release the simple loop operates to return all movie clips to first frame.

```
function mouseReleased() {
     for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {

         eval("box" + i).gotoAndStop(1);
     }
}
```

I have read a number of ways of replacing eval in this forum but I don't know enough javascript to apply them to my situation!

Comment: Put your boxes into an array, instead of using 101 numbered variables.

Comment: We need to know how the box variables are defined.  If they have global scope then you can just change the word eval for window and use square brackets... `window["box" + i].gotoAndStop(1);`

Comment: This worked perfectly and I learnt a lot from this one. Hit a couple of Javascript guides based on your response here and I think the concept of object is starting to sink into my old brain (I'm 46 and don't think like computer code!)

Answer (score 0):

You want to traverse an ordered list of objects. That screams for an array. You can define it like this:

```
 const boxes = [box1, box2, box3 /*...*/];
```

And then its as easy as:

```
 for(const box of boxes)
   box.gotoAndStop(1);
```

Comment: Previous response worked for me but I will be trying this as it seems very elegant. Knowing more than one way to do something never hurts. Thank you.